# BSOD crash. CPU fan turning on and off. The computer won't boot. Processor thermal trip error

Tags: windows-7, boot, cpu, motherboard, bsod

One of my friend's desktop suddenly crashed and is throwing up random symptoms. The following is how the issues have taken place:

1. The Operating System (Windows 7) abruptly crashed with a BSOD error (my friend didn't take a note of the error message)
2. The "computer" refuses to boot. No beeps. No initial start-up screen.
3. We tried pugging out all cables and RAM. We plugged all wires again and re-seated the RAM onto a different slot, and it didn't work.
4. The power supply unit continues to work fine (considering a steady RPM) and the motherboard flashes a LED, indicating steady power input.
5. The next day, we try and the computer easily boots, but stops at the startup screen with the  processor thermal trip error.
6. We unmount the processor fan and processor, we discover the processor is very hot.
7. Now, the processor fan starts and stops after 1 second. And continues this on a loop.
8. We apply a thermal paste, the thermal trip error goes away, but still, the computer won't boot.
9. The processor fan still continues the start and stop after 1 second, on a loop.

What should I do next to troubleshoot? What hardware do you think might be causing the trouble? I strongly feel the motherboard has gone faulty and might be causing these problems. Would that be the case?

Comment: Disconnect all power. Hold down power button for several seconds. Reset the CMOS. Clear BIOS. Reconnect power. See if anything changes and report back.

Comment: After you report back.  You might have to accept something happen to the motherboard.  If the fan is not working on its own when provided power its basically dead.

Comment: its probably the power supply, when you press the power button, and the CPU fan turns on for 1 second and the system shuts down, its the power supply.